# Include html entities in dynamic menu links

Tags: navigation, 10

I implemented a class *CopyrightMenuEntry* extending *MenuLinkDefault* which provides a custom menu entry (without link) with the current year and the site name.

```
class CopyrightMenuEntry extends MenuLinkDefault {
...
public function getTitle() {
  return "&copy;&nbsp;" . $this->year . " " . $this->sitename;
}
publick function getRouteName() {
  return '<nolink>';
}
```

However, this renders as '**&copy;&nbsp;2023 Test**' instead of '**© 2023 Test**'.
Can someone help how to include html entities in the title?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I got one way to solve it:</s>

```
return html_entity_decode('&copy;&nbsp;') . date('Y') . " " . \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
```

see: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Utility!Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AdecodeEntities/8.2.x

Thanks @berliner for the hint at [TranslatableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3A__construct/10):

```
public function getTitle() {
  return $this->t('&copy;&nbsp;@year @sitename', [
    '@year' => date('Y');,
    '@ sitename' => \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name')
  ]);
}
```

This seems like a better solution.

Comment: I didn't test this specific use case, but it would most probably be better to use [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/10) or [TranslatableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3A__construct/10) for this.

Comment: Thank you @berliner. I did edit the answer.